# How i can pass Frequency into the (Rate) parameter in soundpool class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, soundpool

Is there any method to add rate as an frequency in soundpool class. Here is my code.
how can i pass hz(frequency at place of 1f that is rate.

```
fun playSound(v: View) {
        when (v.getId()) {
            R.id.button_sound1 -> {
                soundPool!!.play(sound1!!, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1f)
                //soundPool.pause(sound3StreamId);
//                soundPool!!.autoPause()
            }
            R.id.button_sound2 -> soundPool!!.play(sound1!!, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 0.8f)
            R.id.button_sound3 -> soundPool!!.play(sound1!!, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1.1f)
            R.id.button_sound4 -> soundPool!!.play(sound1!!, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1.4f)
            R.id.button_sound5 -> soundPool!!.play(sound1!!, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1.7f)
            R.id.button_sound6 -> soundPool!!.play(sound1!!, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 2f)
            R.id.button_sound7 -> soundPool!!.play(sound1!!, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 2.3f)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1f 1f - You can check in docs is a volume left and rigth

You change the frequency - in Your sound file. If You put there 20 hz it will be 20 kHz if You put there 64 kHz it will play 64 kHz.

```
metronome2 = this.soundPool.load(gameSurface.app.context, R.raw.metronome2wav, 1);
```

check properties of this file.
`pb`